# How can I fix the following error? AttributeError: 'ID3DecisionTreeClassifer' object has no attribute '_ID3DecisionTreeClassifer__fit'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am getting the following error:  AttributeError: 'ID3DecisionTreeClassifer' object has no attribute '_ID3DecisionTreeClassifer__fit'

My result must be
0

1

0

0

1

1

1

but I get an error instead. I am trying to build a decision tree API. I already implemented a _traverse method, which will recursively traverse a decision tree dictionary that is produced by the make_tree function.

```
class ID3DecisionTreeClassifer(object): 
   
def __init__(self):
       
pass
   
def fit(self, X, y):
    
self.splits_ = make_tree(X,y)# YOUR CODE to generate the decision tree 
dictionary 
 
def _majority_vote(self, label_array):
  
counter = counter(lable_array)
   
 max_vote = max(counter.values())
    
counter = {v:k for k, v in counter.items()}
   
 return counter[max_vote]# YOUR CODE
  
def _traverse(self, x, d):
    
if isinstance(d, np.ndarray):
        
return d 
     
for key in d:
      
  name, value = key.split(' = ') 
       
 feature_idx = int(name.split('_')[-1])
       
 value = int(value)
         
 if x[feature_idx] == value:
           
 return self._traverse(x, d[key]) 
   
def predict(self, x):
       
label_array = self._traverse(x,self.__fit) # YOUR CODE to get class 

labels from the 

target node 
       
return self._majority_vote(label_array)#YOUR CODE to predict the class 
label via 
 majority voting
                #from label_array

 # DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE BELOW CELL

 tree = ID3DecisionTreeClassifer() 

 tree.fit(X, y)

 print(tree.predict(np.array([0, 0]))) 

 print(tree.predict(np.array([0, 1]))) 

 print(tree.predict(np.array([1, 0]))) 

 print(tree.predict(np.array([1, 0]))) 

 print(tree.predict(np.array([1, 1]))) 

 print(tree.predict(np.array([2, 0]))) 

 print(tree.predict(np.array([2, 1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an indentation problem. When I ran the code with proper indentation, I could call the fit() function.

Since fit() is a function of the ID3DecisionTreeClassifer class, the indentation should look like this:

```
class ID3DecisionTreeClassifer(object): 
   
 def __init__(self):
       
  pass
   
 def fit(self, X, y):
    
  self.splits_ = make_tree(X,y)
 
 def _majority_vote(self, label_array):
 ...
```

Comment: My indentation id correct in my code. Could you have the following result? 1

0

0

1

1

1